# How to shape footnotes horizontally?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, footnotes

Hi

I'm writing a little paragraph and want to write my footnotes horizontally.

How can I do that?

for example here my footnotes are 6x1 and I want something 1x6 or 2x3(I need a option that I can change the shape).

below is the code:

```
\begin{document}
%\maketitle
\chapter*{\centering Throwing all Money from the window}
    In dangerous car chase in L.A recently, bank robbers who were running away\footnote{escaping} from the police, launched\footnote{throw} all the taken\footnote{stolen} money from the window. The disturbance \footnote{incident} began in northern suburb of the city where a armed bank robbery had been committed.the robbers escaped in a stolen vehicle and two of them who have not been arrested\footnote{caught}, tried to jump out of the car.
    All along the chasing\footnote{route} one of the suspects ,who had set in the back seat of the car, threw handfuls of bank notes out of the window. 
\end{document}
```

I would appreciate your solutions.

Comment: with help `\usepackage[para]{footmisc}`?

Comment: You surely need a `\documentclass` to make that compilable. Please add it. You should not have `\centering` in the argument to `\chapter*`.